# Connecting to SQL Server using odbc mssql with Adodb5 on Linux / Mac

Tags: php, linux, odbc, adodb

I cannot connect to a SQL server database from my Mac. Here's my PHP code:

```
$db = &ADONewConnection('odbc_mssql');
$db->debug = true;
$myDSN="DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=XXX.XXX.XXX.XX;PORT=1433;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXXX;DATABASE=XXXXX;";
    $db->Connect($myDSN);
```

I've tried a whole bunch of different drivers (FreeTDS, SQL SERVER, SQL Server Native Client etc.) but I keep getting this error:

```
SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002
```

FYI, I've installed php5-mssql, freetds and unixODBC.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The error is trying to tell you that you do not have a "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" on your machine.

This comes as no surprise since the SQL Server Native Client is only available on Windows.

What you need is a third party ODBC driver (or the like) such as the [OpenLink Single-tier ODBC Driver for SQL Server](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sqlserver-st/)

Comment: For anyone else who finds this page, Microsoft recently released a Linux version of SQL Server native Client 11.0.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28160